# How to Fix this using Css

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I have `menu` that is implemented with html and css.

On `mouseover` of main `menu`, I have to show all `submenus` in one place.

Here is an example [click here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aur56/)

For this, the `submenus` alignement is not proper.

According to the example, Test 5 has to come under Test 2 but, it's showing blank space.

How can I align this properly?

Note:: The `Submenu` items will be dynamic, they may grow or shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible with your current markup: if Test5 had to go below Test2, then how would you automatically tell it not to go below Test1? What should the rule be? There's no obvious answer to your question: if you need elements of different size to layout in a space efficient manner, without too much blank space, etc, you could write some kind of layout manager with jQuery that will structure and re-position your menus according to their content.

Comment: the total thing is dynamic, based on different logins i have to show differnt submenus so can you show how it's possible with jquery

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your submenus are floating left and Test 5 is getting hung up on Test 3 because it is longer than Test 4.

You can test this by adding a CSS rule to set the submenus to have the same height.

```
ul .sub.sub10 ul{
 height:180px;
}
```

[Link to updated jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aur56/5/)